# Change output directory for gPodder

Tags: download, podcasts, podcatcher

I'd like to change directory gPodder downloads podcasts to. Default output directory in Ubuntu is `~/gPodder/Downloads/`. I cannot find output directory in config. How I can change output directory for gPodder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ubuntu**:
Add a line `GPODDER_DOWNLOAD_DIR=/new/output/path/` to the file `~/.pam_environment`. Relogin Ubuntu to make changes take effect.

**Windows**: Set an environment variable `GPODDER_DOWNLOAD_DIR` to desired output folder.

[source](https://gpodder.github.io/docs/user-manual.html#gpodder-home-folder-and-download-location)